# Submenu on hover

Tags: html, css, navigation, submenu

I´m trying to make a submenu on hover for hours, read about ten tutorials or more and finally don't get it working. 
I want it to show "Zimmer", "Reservierung" and "Preise" in a vertical menu if I hover "Hotel" and so on.
This is my code:

```css
a {
    text-decoration: none;}
nav {
 height: 50px;
 clear: both;}
nav ul {
 padding: 5px 0px;
 text-align: center;}
nav li {
 margin: 0px;
 display: inline;
 padding: 0px;}
nav li a {
 font-size: 18px;
 color: #775923;
 padding: 0px 20px;
 margin: 0px;}
nav li a:hover, nav li a.current {
 color: #775923;
    padding: 0px 20px 14px 20px;
 -webkit-padding-after: 15px;
 box-shadow: 0 4px #b1d130;} 
nav ul ul{
 display: none;} 
nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;}
```

```html
<nav>
     <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="current">Willkommen</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Hotel</a></li>
             <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Zimmer</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Reservierung</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Preise</a></li>
                </ul>
            <li><a href="#">Restaurant</a></li>
             <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Speisekarte</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Anlässe</a></li>
                </ul>
            <li><a href="#">Anfahrt</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
             <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Über Uns</a></li>
                </ul>                
        </ul>
</nav>
```

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/AuJeF/445/

Hope you can help.
Thank you

Comment: Your `ul` is not part of your li hierarchy. So you're saying `li:hover ul` applies to no elements. If you make it a child of the `li` that would work, or you could say `li:hover + ul` which will target the `ul` directly following the `li`.

Comment: This should get you on your way http://jsfiddle.net/AuJeF/446/

Comment: This is what i need to find my way. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the problem on your markup,
change as following-

```
       <li><a href="#">Hotel</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Zimmer</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Reservierung</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Preise</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

(this is a simple dropdown menu)

```
 <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="current">Willkommen</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Hotel</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Zimmer</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Reservierung</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Preise</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Restaurant</a><ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Speisekarte</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Anlässe</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li> 
        </ul>
</nav>
```

**css**

```
nav
{
    margin-top:15px
}

nav ul
{
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}

nav ul a
{
    display:block;
    color:#333;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:700;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:32px;
    padding:0 15px;
    font-family:"HelveticaNeue","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif
}

nav ul li
{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}

nav ul li.current-menu-item
{
    background:#ddd
}

nav ul li:hover
{
    background:#f6f6f6
}

nav ul ul
{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
    background:#fff;
    padding:0
}

nav ul ul li
{
    float:none;
    width:200px
}

nav ul ul a
{
    line-height:120%;
    padding:10px 15px
}

nav ul ul ul
{
    top:0;
    left:100%
}

nav ul li:hover > ul
{
    display:block
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/axtf4doa/)

Answer (score 0):

the mistake in you html. ul > ul mast be insite li. But not outsideю

```
<li><a href="#">Hotel</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Zimmer</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Reservierung</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Preise</a></li>
                </ul>
</li>
```

You're writing style - if ul inside li then ul display block. But inside li no ul it after him.
Will validator error, because tag ul inside >ul that's not true, there can be only >li
Think, I help U